# Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun <T : Context!> getApplicationContext(): T! Please specify it explicitly

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, compiler-errors, robolectric

I am trying to write some tests for my android app and it's really chalanging for me. One of many obsticles is this error

```
Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun <T : Context!> getApplicationContext(): T! Please specify it explicitly.
```

which occures on this line

```
val actualIntent: Intent = shadowOf(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())
            .nextStartedActivity
```

Full test code looks like this

```
@Test
fun clickingLogin_shouldStartLoginActivity() {
    val scenario = launch(LogInActivity::class.java)

    scenario.onActivity { activity ->
        activity.go_to_register_button.performClick()
        val expectedIntent = Intent(activity, RegistrationActivity::class.java)
        val actual: Intent = shadowOf(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())
            .nextStartedActivity

        expectedIntent.component shouldBeEqualTo actual.component
    }
}
```

Basically the shadowOf function is overloaded and can return many thinks and I need to specify the type.

I believe it should be somethink like `shadowOf<SomeType>(...)` But I have no idea what the actual type should be.

Any help would be really appreciated.

**EDIT**
I am following roboloctric [guideline](http://robolectric.org/writing-a-test/) but trying to write it in an androidX way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not have asked as clearly as I should have. But for anyone who landed here stucked with the same problem here is a solution.

I did not figure out how to test if an activity is producing correct intents in normal tests. But in instrumented tests it goes like this:

```
@get:Rule
var activityRule: IntentsTestRule<MyActivity> =
        IntentsTestRule(MyActivity::class.java)

@Test
fun testIntent () {

  // perform some actions
  // than verify
  intended(hasComponent(OtherActicity::class.qualifiedName))
  intended(hasExtra(A_CONSTANT, someValue))
}
```

You need a dependency for this to work

`androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.1.0'`

[more info here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/intents)

Answer (score 1):

An `Intent` is a different type of `Object` that does not extend from `Context`.

this line :

`val actualIntent: Intent = shadowOf(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())`

provides a `Context` as an argument, and returns a `ShadowContext`, not an `Intent`.

docs ref : http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.0/org/robolectric/Shadows.html#shadowOf-android.content.Context-

Basically it is telling you that a tree can't be a type of car.

Comment: but the line continues with .nextStartedActivity

Comment: You could type anything after, and it would be the same - this is purely an inheritance issue.